# How to add a proper-looking text input field to Firefox toolbar?

Tags: html, firefox, interface, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to have a text input field in toolbar that looks like search input and is controlled by a FF extension.

I am using sdk/widget:

in main js file I have

```
var reason = require("sdk/widget").Widget({
  label: "Progress Block - reason",
  id: "text-entry",
  contentURL: data.url("reason.html"),
  width: 120
});
```

in reason html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <style type="text/css" media="all">
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <input type="text" style="width: 105px; height: 16px;">
    </body> 
</html>
```

With this style input field is absurdly small, but at least FF displays it - without style scrollbars are displayed.

Without style - I wanted something like search field, I got scrollbar:
[image: without any style]

After adding width style:
[image: with only width style]

With style as posted:
[image: with style]

What is the proper way to have a well formed text input in toolbar controlled by an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would insert a textfield with CustomizableUI.jsm type custom and build the thing.

This is how to make custom type customizazbleui.jsm stuff: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/10902477

I tried to find how the searchbar was created, i would have though it was also done via customizableui.jsm but i couldnt find it on mxr.

edit:

this is how:

```
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import('resource:///modules/CustomizableUI.jsm');
CustomizableUI.createWidget({
    id: 'myCUITextbox',
    type: 'custom',
    removable: true,
    defaultArea: CustomizableUI.AREA_NAVBAR,
    onBuild: function(aDocument) {
        var node = aDocument.createElement('toolbaritem');
        node.setAttribute('id', this.id);

        var props = {
          title: 'Search',
          align: 'center',
          class: 'chromeclass-toolbar-additional panel-wide-item',
          flex: 100
        };
        for (var p in props) {
          node.setAttribute(p, props[p])
        }

        var textbox = aDocument.createElement('textbox');
        node.appendChild(textbox);

        //node.style.listStyleImage = "url(" + (aProvider.icon32URL || aProvider.iconURL) + ")";
        return node;
    }
});
```

And when you want to remove do:

```
CustomizableUI.destroyWidget('myCUITextbox');
```

Comment: How can I use text entered by user into this text box? I found plenty of documentation about reacting to creation/removal of widget, reacting to clicking on button (only for the button widget) but nothing that would allow to use entered text.

Comment: Those widget interaction things are not what you want. What you want is within the onBuild do a `textbox.addEventListener`. Of course you can use those widget things, then in the `event` do `event.target.childNodes` blah blah till you get your textnode :)

Comment: I added ```textbox.setAttribute('id', "someid");``` what allows me to use ```win.document.getElementById("someid").value``` - both for querying and setting value of textbox. I based my solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336163/getting-the-contents-of-the-toolbar-search-box-using-the-mozilla-firefox-add-on

Answer (score 0):

The widget api has been deprecated and you should not use it. If you look at the browser console, you'll see messages from the SDK warning about this deprecation.

Instead, you should be using the newer UI elements introduced with Firefox 29 like the toolbar api:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui#Toolbar

Comment: I know, but Australis introduced separation of normal toolbar and add-on toolbar what is not acceptable for me ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730618/replace-deprecated-sdk-widget-without-using-toolbar-from-australis ).

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Don't know what to tell you - we did that for real reasons. Isn't there some way you can inject custom css to correct your styling problems?