# How to have a free text input field (textbox) in a toolbar widget with Firefox Addon-SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using Firefox Addon-SDK to create a toolbar for learning purpose which takes free text and search the webpage for that text, something which <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> does.  Based on the SDK documentation, I was able to create a normal button, toggle button, etc. But, I couldn't find anywhere how to create a textbox to take string as input.

How do I create a textbox in the toolbar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556770/how-to-add-a-proper-looking-text-input-field-to-firefox-toolbar/27560934#27560934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with the SDK, use a [frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_frame).

> it can be used in conjunction with a[`Toolbar`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_toolbar): you create a`Frame`, then supply it to the `Toolbar`'s constructor, and the content is then displayed inside the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks :) It worked perfectly. Mozilla should provide easier way to add the basic ui elements.