# How to create an addon that adds a text box to the Firefox's navigation bar in FF40+?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Up until Firefox 39, the Widget component of the SDK allowed me to put text and html on the navigation bar.

This is how the Widget looked like in Firefox 39:
https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/previews/full/141/141276.png?modified=1407874117

Now with the latest SDK the best I could do is either

- add a ui.Frame to a separated toolbar (that ends up mostly empty because users only want a small text label displayed) or
- dropping a ui.Frame in the navigation bar with the drag&drop. But for some reason this text box triples the height of the Firefox's navigation bar, even if the ui.Frame only contains one character. See this from a user's complain: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCbv_g5x1Z0WFU1dThXU3BkcHM/view?usp=sharing

The HTML that is loaded in the ui.Frame is simple as:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body id="tickers-body">
    <div> 430$ </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556770/how-to-add-a-proper-looking-text-input-field-to-firefox-toolbar/27560934?s=1|0.9358#27560934 uses CustomizableUI.jsm which is unchanged since FF29 and will hopefully only undergo HTML'isation in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I really hope the CustomizableUI.jsm has a long life ahead. With your reference I was able to write my own Widget in the navigation bar that displays custom html documents and feeds them with data from the addon. In case someone is interested in the solution, here is my working code: https://github.com/neoranga55/bitcoin-price-ticker/tree/firefox-customizable-ui

Comment: Fantastic job @Sebas, yes the CUI.jsm module is absolutely amazing!